# Tem como usar o :focus em div?

Tags: css

Tenho um *div* que segura meu *input* e *submit*, ai queria colocar um efeito pra ficar mais legal, só que eu tentei usar assim *.busca:focus* e não funcionou, alguém saberia como eu poderia colocar um efeito focus nessa *div* ?

```
<div class="busca">
    <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer aplicar um estilo na `div` quando o `input` receber o foco?

Comment: Bem-vindo, faça um tour começando por esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: sim, tipo o usuario clica na div `busca` ai exibe uma borda e um background, os exemplos abaixo alguns funcionam mais não chegaram no ponto que eu preciso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a ideia é aplicar algum estilo na `div` quando um dos campos recebe o foco, eu indicaria utilizar o próprio evento `focus` do *input* e acessar a *div* através do atributo `parentElement`.

Veja abaixo um exemplo que altera a cor de fundo da *div* quando o campo recebe o foco. Perceba que funcionará independente da forma que o foco é dado ao campo, seja navegação por *tabs* ou auto foco.

```js
const busca = document.getElementById("busca");
const inputs = busca.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (const input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
    this.parentElement.style.background = "green";
  });
  
  input.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
    this.parentElement.style.background = "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="busca">
    <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Pra quem busca uma solução mais simples, agora o CSS possui um seletor chamado `:focus-within` cujo objetivo é selecionar o elemento pai quando um elemento filho sofre o foco.

```
.busca:focus-within {
 /* Muda o background color da div pai */
 background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você der foco à div, não será possível dar foco ao input para digitar algo.

Solução de acordo com o comentário `tipo o usuario clica na div busca ai exibe uma borda e um background`, foi dito, **clica na div busca** e não em `algum elemento da div busca`

Nesse caso a solução é, como os demais exemplos, aplicar um estilo a div simulando foco

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".busca").click(function(e){
           $(this).addClass("selected");
           e.stopPropagation();
       });   
       $(document).click(function(){ 
           $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
       });
    });
```

```css
.selected{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 10, 10);
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busca" id="onFocus">
        <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    <p>Faço parte da div</p>
    </div>
```

### Outras soluções

**Exemplo 2**

```html
<div class="busca"  onclick="this.style.cssText = 'border: 2px solid #96BED9;'">
    <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    </div>
```

**Exemplo 3**

```html
    <div class="busca" onclick="this.style.cssText = 'box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 10, 10);'">
    <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    </div>
```

[style Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536498(v=VS.85).aspx)

> você poderá editar o CSS apara aplicar o efeito desejado

**Exemplo 4** - uso de Jquery. Solução completa pois ao clicar fora da div o estilo é removido

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".busca").click(function(e){
           $(this).addClass("selected");
           e.stopPropagation();
           document.getElementById('onFocus').style.backgroundColor = "red";
       });   
       $(document).click(function(){ 
           $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
           document.getElementById('onFocus').style.backgroundColor = "";
       });
    });
```

```css
.selected{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);

    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busca" id="onFocus">
        <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    </div>
```

---

**A idéia de aplicar foco a div que contem um input com entrada de dados faz este input ficar inviabilizado** (só vai conseguir digitar se mantiver o ponteiro do mouse clicado nele).

**Veja o exemplo abaixo**

```js
document.getElementById('onFocus').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('onFocus').focus();
};
```

```css
div:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
 <div class="busca" tabindex="-1" id="onFocus">
 <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    </div>
```

**Exemplo 5 - Com background definido no CSS também funciona**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".busca").click(function(e){
           $(this).addClass("selected");
           e.stopPropagation();
       });   
       $(document).click(function(){ 
           $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
       });
    });
```

```css
.selected{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 10, 10);
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busca" id="onFocus">
        <input type="text" name="" class="txt txt_busca" placeholder="faça sua pesquisa"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="bt bt_busca" value="OK"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Antes de vc editar a resposta estava mais legal ao clicar fora da div e voltar ao normal. :)

Comment: @Dvdsamm coloquei o exemplo explicando o porque não rola `:focus` em div

Comment: Legal. De qq forma acho bobo querer fazer focus em div rs... mas essa era a pergunta neh, fazer oq. Mas sua resposta ficou completa. +1

Comment: o exemplo de clicar fora do `div` é mais legal, porém não funciona se colocar um background, e eu precisaria que mudasse a borda e o background

Comment: Aqui só funcionou com o `box-shadow` tentei colocar o `background` porém não obtive sucesso

Comment: @mayron2017 background foi via javascript, veja lá na resposta editada

Comment: sem sucesso amigo, não sei se estou colocando o código no lugar errado, mais creio que não, só funciona a `box-shadow` mesmo

Comment: @mayron2017 me diga o seguinte, na minha resposta funciona pra você?

Comment: tive sucesso, foi desatenção minha, funciona sim, só que eu voto em positivo e diz que eu tenho que ter 15 pontos de reputação mais mesmo assim meu voto e guardado, só não é mostrado

Comment: @mayron2017 veja no final da resposta com backgound no CSS

Comment: encontrei outro problema, ele só funciona pra uma `div`, e eu tenho 5 campos no meu form, no caso eu teria que expecificar o `jquery` pra cada div

Comment: nesse caso é melhor fazer outra pergunta colocando o seu código para que as respostas dadas não fiquem fora do foco.