# Como colocar um efeito :focus na div

Tags: css

Tenho 5 *input* e cada um fica dentro de um *div*, gostaria de saber como colocar um efeito *focus* em cada *div* que segura o *input* e ao clicar fora da div remover o efeito.

```
<div class="input">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome..."
 </div>
```

Comment: E porque você não usa o :focus no input? (Me parece que você terá de usar um css para pintar a borda da div, simulando um focus)

Comment: Porque  a `span` tem o efeito como se estivesse dentro do input, com CSS não tem como colocar o `focus` na `div`, creio que com `js` teria como só não sei como fazer

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tem como usar o :focus em div?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243448/tem-como-usar-o-focus-em-div)

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o evento de foco na div não tem como aplicar.
Mas você poderá conseguir o que está buscando com javascript, utilizando esse exemplo ficaria assim:

```
function fOnFocus(){
     this.parentNode.classList.add("div-focus");
}

function fOnBlur(){
     this.parentNode.classList.remove("div-focus");
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");

for (var indice = 0; indice < inputs.length; indice++) {  
  var input = inputs[indice];
  input.onfocus = fOnFocus;
  input.onblur = fOnBlur;
}
```

Nesse caso bastaria criar uma classe div-focus no seu CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Como dito no  [**post anterior**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243448/tem-como-usar-o-focus-em-div/243455#243455) "Se você der foco a div, não será possível dar foco ao input para digitar algo" a solução é aplicar um estilo a div simulando foco.

No HTML coloque nos `ids` das `divs` as respectivas classes CSS.

No script recupere esse valor a aplique na função `addClass`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".busca").click(function(){
       var status = $(this).attr('id');
       $(this).addClass(status);
    });
    
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
    var container = $(".busca");
    if (!container.is(e.target))  
    {
       //procura elementos cuja ID começa por uma dada string, neste caso estilo
       //https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
       $('div[id^="estilo"]').removeClass(); 
    }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.estilo1{
    box-shadow: 0 0 36px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 25, 10, 10);
    background-color: green !important;
}

.estilo2{
    box-shadow: 0 0 36px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(25, 255, 10, 10);
    background-color: red !important;
}

.estilo3{
    box-shadow: 0 0 36px rgba(0, 0, 238, 1);
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(25, 25, 10, 10);
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

.estilo4{
    border: 2px solid #96BED9;
    background-color: gray !important;
}

.estilo5{
    border: 4px solid #FF00FF;
    background-color: azure !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="estilo1" class="busca">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome...">
 </div>
 
 <div id="estilo2" class="busca">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome...">
 </div>
 
 <div id="estilo3" class="busca">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome...">
 </div>
 
  <div id="estilo4" class="busca">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome...">
 </div>
  
  <div id="estilo5" class="busca">
    <span>Nome <strong>*</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt txt_nome" placeholder="seu nome...">
 </div>
```

> Nota: o efeito é clicando em qualquer parte da `div` e não em `um elemento especifico dentro da div` reveja [**post anterior**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243448/tem-como-usar-o-focus-em-div/243455#243455)

Comment: perfeito esse exemplo era oque eu precisava, só teria um problema, como remover o background quando o usuário clica fora da `div`?

Comment: ta legal amigo, você me ajudou bastante obrigado

Comment: @mayron2017, vou editar sua pergunta de modo a haver compatibilidade com a minha resposta!!